# How to upgrade the project build in visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, upgrade, opc

I have one OPC ( OLE for Process control ) server project which is developed into visual studio 2005. I want to run it in visual studio 2008. The coding for the OPC server project is done in VC++. I want to connect my OPC client to this OPC server. When I was opened the OPC server project which was build into visual studio 2005 into visual studio 2008 first time it was asking for conversion wizard. I gone through that wizard & successfully finished that wizard. But when I build ( by right clicking on the project & choosing build solution ) it is giving lots of error near about 64 errors. Most of the errors are like - fetal error C1083:Can not open type library file:'msxml4.dll':No such file or directory, fetal error LINK1181:can not open input file 'rpcndr.lib' , error C2051:case expression not constant. only these 3 types of errors in am getting. All these 3 errors are repeated in Error list & becoming bunch of 64 errors. Please provide me the solution for the above issue. Can you provide me any suusgestion or link or any way through whcih I can resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening in VS 2008 is the only way to upgrade.

But it looks like you need to clean up some of the references... this will be a manual step (likely just need to set a few paths). Start by fixing the first error, it is likely many of the subsequent errors are a consequence of that first error.

Normal practice is to have a copy of referenced libraries (including typelibs) somewhere in your source tree, so you are not dependent on absolute paths into the OS or other application's install folders. (Or the continuing existence of that library).

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio Project go to Project properties dialog to use Linker --> Input Options:
1. Remove rpcndr.lib 
2. Make sure for all such configurations add rpcrt4.lib
Reason to do this is that the Windows SDK no longer ships with rpcndr.lib.