# LNK1104: cannot open file 'rpcndr4.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, visual-studio-2005, porting, platform-sdk

I was working in VS2005 in WindowsXP 64-bit platform and now I am converting all my projects in to VS2010 in Windows7 64-bit. While building one of my project I am getting a link error "LNK1104: cannot open file rpcndr.lib". The project builds in VS2005 without any issues in my machine.

Whether its anything related to Platform SDK..? otherwise what's the solution for this issue.?

I read from a link that I have to install latest platform SDK to solve this issue.
I tried to download platform SDK 4.0 for Windows7 but it always get failed in my machine by stopping download infinitely.

Regards,
Nixon

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613177/how-to-upgrade-the-project-build-in-visual-studio-2005-to-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 3):

> Whether its anything related to Platform SDK..? otherwise what's the solution for this issue.?

SOLUTION TO QUESTION:
 'rpcndr4.lib' is obsolete in the new SDK, so just edit your project > Props > Linker > input > Addition Dep..:  and remove 'rpcndr4.lib'

> I read from a link that I have to install latest platform SDK to solve this issue. I tried to download platform SDK 4.0 for Windows7 but it always get failed in my machine by stopping download infinitely.

WORKAROUND:
I had same problem.  So I downloaded SDK onto my Windows-7 32-bit laptop without problem, then copied it to my Win-7 64-bit desktop.

Comment: Thank you! I already solved the issue with your first option.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue from the comment mentioned in the below website:
https://henbo.wordpress.com/2006/11/22/lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-rpcndr-lib/

> You also need to remove comment out the line
>
> //#pragma comment(lib, “rpcndr.lib”)
>
> in the dlldatax.c file